# Отправка нужных данных на почту из формы на сайте

Tags: javascript, php

Есть форма на сайте с помощью которой пользователь может выбрать нужную ему организацию и в поле ниже подставится нужный ему ИНН через js, мне нужно этот ИНН передать как то на почту, но программа берет только последний ИНН и передает его, или берет сразу все. Подскажите пожалуйста как правильно это реализовать?

```
<select name="myorganizations1" class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlSelect1" onChange="Selected(this)">
                 <option selected value="компания1" >компания1 </option>
                 <option value="компания2" >компания2 </option>
                 <option value="компания3" >компания3 </option>
```

```
    <div id="Label1" class="form-group">
    <label for="exampleFormControlInput1">ИНН</label>
    <input type="text" name="inn1" readonly class="form-control" id="staticEmail" value="123">
  </div>
    <div id="Label2" class="form-group" style="display:none">
    <label for="exampleFormControlInput1">ИНН</label>
    <input type="text" name="inn2" readonly class="form-control" id="staticEmail" value="1234">
  </div>
    <div id="Label3" class="form-group" style="display:none">
    <label for="exampleFormControlInput1">ИНН</label>
    <input type="text" name="inn3" readonly class="form-control" id="staticEmail" value="12345">
  </div>
  <script>
function Selected(a) {
    var label = a.value;
    if (label=="компания1") {
        document.getElementById("Label1").style.display='block';
        document.getElementById("Label2").style.display='none';
        document.getElementById("Label3").style.display='none';

    } else if (label=="компания2") {
        document.getElementById("Label1").style.display='none';
        document.getElementById("Label2").style.display='block';
        document.getElementById("Label3").style.display='none';

    } else if (label=="компания3") {
        document.getElementById("Label1").style.display='none';
        document.getElementById("Label2").style.display='none';
        document.getElementById("Label3").style.display='block';

    } else {
        document.getElementById("Label1").style.display='block';
        document.getElementById("Label2").style.display='none';
        document.getElementById("Label3").style.display='none';
    }

}

</script>
<?php
/* Здесь проверяется существование переменных */

if (isset($_POST['myorganizations1'])) {$myorganizations1 = $_POST['myorganizations1'];}
if (isset($_POST['inn1'])) {$inn1 = $_POST['inn1'];}
if (isset($_POST['inn2'])) {$inn2 = $_POST['inn2'];}
if (isset($_POST['inn3'])) {$inn3 = $_POST['inn3'];}


/* Сюда впишите свою эл. почту */
$myaddres  = ""; // кому отправляем

/* А здесь прописывается текст сообщения, \n - перенос строки */
$mes = "Заказ акта сверки на E-mail: $staticEmail\n
Поставщик: $myorganizations1\n
ИНН: $inn1\n ";//что нужно написать чтобы выбирался нужный инн?

/* А эта функция как раз занимается отправкой письма на указанный вами email */
$sub='компании'; //сабж
$email=''; // от кого
//$send = mail ($myaddres,$sub,$mes,"Content-type:text/plain; charset = utf-8\r\nFrom:$email");

if (mail($myaddres,$sub,$mes,"Content-type:text/plain; charset = utf-8\r\nFrom:$email"))
 {
    echo '<p style="margin-top: 20px;border: 1px solid;width: 30%;padding: 10px;">Cообщение успешно отправлено</p>';
} else {
    echo '<p style="margin-top: 20px;border: 1px solid;width: 30%;padding: 10px;">При отправке сообщения возникли ошибки</p>';
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
function Selected(a) {
    // выбранное значение из селекта надо получать так
    var label = a.options[a.selectedIndex].value;
    ...
}
```

Чтобы не плодить инпуты для ИНН можете сам ИНН хранить в том же `option`, а при выборе из списка, подставлять соответствующее значение в поле ИНН.

```html
<form>
  <select name="myorganizations1" class="form-control" onChange="Selected(this)">
      <option selected value="компания1" data-inn="4578770909">компания1 </option>
      <option value="компания2" data-inn="5578770909">компания2 </option>
      <option value="компания3" data-inn="6578770909">компания3 </option>
  </select>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="inputInn">ИНН</label>
    <input type="text" name="inn" readonly class="form-control" id="inputInn">
  </div>
</form>
<script>
function Selected(select) {
    var inputInn = document.getElementById("inputInn");
    if(select.selectedIndex > -1){
        var option = select.options[select.selectedIndex];
        inputInn.value = option.dataset.inn;
    }else{
        inputInn.value = '';
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Спасибо вам большое